# If strring a 65c soup causes small fish to tear up, does it mean it's overcooked?

Tags: fish, soup, thermometer, overcooking

The fish in question is whitebait, I slowly bring the fish and soup water up to 65c then remove from stove.  During the cooking period I stir the pot to overcome/distrubute higher temperature at bottom of pot. As this happens I notice fish tears apart with stirring.  Considering the water is at max 65c, is the broken fish a sign of overcooking?

If the water is 65c, I would think the fish reaches 50-55 at most or do you think it also reaches 65c?  I can't find any suitable thermometers for whitebait(which are 40-50mm long) so am just going by water temperature and guessing what the fish temperature might be.

Comment: I've noticed you post a lot of questions about cooking whitebait, and you seem to be having a lot of trouble with it.  You keep trying though, so I think it must be a pretty common food where you live.  If that's the case (and maybe even if it isn't), have you considered asking someone nearby who knows how to cook whitebait well to show you how?  Then you could get better feedback about where you're going wrong than strangers on the internet can give.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's pretty much just a sign it's cooked. One of the common tests for doneness for fish is that the layers flake apart. For something that small, that means the whole fish can break up.

It could *also* be overcooked (it's not like it stops being flaky once it gets at all past cooked) but it can't be *that* badly overcooked at that temperature.